# How are answers with the same score ordered?

Tags: support, answers

I recently answered a question [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/why-do-my-npcs-love-each-other) 2 minutes later, another person answered the question.

I noticed that after visiting the question a few more times, my answer seemed to switch with the other answer and vice-versa a couple of times. Both of our answers have 0 score, there are no other answers, and mine answered first.

My question is, **how do you determine the order of answers with the same score**? I would have thought that it is based on when the answers were written, but since these answers are switching, it can't be the case.

Comment: There are [quite a few questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=answer+order) on this topic at [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is random at each page-load, so that one is not favoured over the other. Higher questions are more likely to be read/voted upon, hence randomising it helps make sure all have equal exposure.

Comment: This makes sense. I was thinking of it like that.